# EntityFieldQuery not returning Bundle data

Tags: entities

I've defined an entity in `hook_entity_info` as follows:

```
function foo_entity_info() {
  return array(
    'Foo' => array(
      'label' => t('foo'), 
      'base table' => 'foo',                                       
      'entity keys' => array(          
        'id' => 'bar',          
        'label' => 'bar',
      ),
      'module' => 'foo',          
      'fieldable' => TRUE,
      'bundles' => array(
        'Foo' => array(
          'label' => t('Foo'),
          'admin' => array(
              'path' => 'admin/config/foo/fields',
              'access arguments' => array('access content'),
          ),   
        ),
      ),
      'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController',
    ),
  );
}
```

When I run the following code:

`$info = entity_get_info('Foo');` it all looks OK

When I run the following code:

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type','Foo');
  $result = $query->execute();
```

it all looks OK

But when I run the following code:

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type','Foo')
    ->entityCondition('bundle','Foo');
  $result = $query->execute();
```

I get an empty array in `$result`. This seems wrong.

What should I expect to see in `$result` and why aren't I seeing it?

Many thanks,

MB

Answer (score 0):

> What should I expect to see in $result

You should expect to see an array of data that represents the entities that match your query. This array will contain a key for each entity type it returns, and an array within each of those keyed by the individual entity IDs. The inner-most array will contain bundle key data for the entity. You will need to run the ID(s) through `entity_load()` or equivalent if you want access to general field/property data for the entities.

> why aren't I seeing it?

Not really possible to say without more information. If you know that you have existing entities that match the criteria, and they're not showing up in an EFQ, that's potentially the sign of a deeper problem with your installation (or it might not be, it depends).

If that's the case, clear your caches and try again. If that doesn't fix it, reinstall your entity module. After that, you're left with step-debugging to find out what DB query is being produced, you can run that against MySQL proper to see what's going on, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Clive - does my entity definition in ``hook_entity_info`` look correct, particularly the 'bundle' part of it?

Comment: Looks fine to me - but why do you ask?

Comment: Because the EFQ works fine when I query by 'entity_type', but fails when I query by 'entity_type' and 'bundle'. So I wondered if I'd misdefined the bundle somehow. (This is my first go at a custom entity).

Comment: I stepped through entity.inc and this is where my bundle query is coming undone: `if (isset($this->entityConditions['bundle'])) {
      if (!empty($entity_info['entity keys']['bundle'])) {
        $this->addCondition($select_query, $base_table . '.' . $sql_field, $this->entityConditions['bundle'], $having);
      }
      else {
        // This entity has no bundle, so invalidate the query.
        $select_query->where('1 = 0');
      }
    }` - so it looks like I have to set **['entity keys']['bundle']** to something non-null. What should it be set to? I don't understand the docs.